# Using setdiff to compare multiple columns in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

I have a matrix X with 3 columns [x1 x2 x3] and n rows. I have a second matrix Y with three columns [y1 y2 y3] and m rows. I would like to return all rows from X which are not identical to rows in Y.

I have been trying to use the setdiff function to do this but I can't work out how to use this function to compare columns simultaneously (ie compare [x1 y1] [x2 y2] [x3 y3]) and base the output on this comparison instead of basing the output on a single column comparison.

I would like the result to be:
For some row i of X being equal to some row j of Y [x1 x2 x3] = [y1 y2 y3] then the row of X will be excluded in the output of the new X.

Answer (score 1):

`setdiff` iterates over both arguments, what you need to do is create a collection of rows for both matrices. This might not be the most efficient way but it works:

```
x = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 10 11 12]
xrows = Vector()
for i in 1:size(x, 1)
    push!(xrows, x[i, :])
end

y = [1 1 1 ; 4 5 6; 9 9 9]
yrows = Vector()
for i in 1:size(y, 1)
    push!(yrows, y[i, :])
end

vcat(setdiff(xrows, yrows)...)
```

Comment: Thanks this works. It doesn't seem like the vcat in the last line does anything though.

Comment: the 'vcat' concatenates the resulting rows, so the final result is a matrix rather than a "vector of rows".

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include the ... since I didn't know what they meant. I see that it works now. However I don't understand the ... I have read up a bit about it but it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: `...` "separates" the components of the vector of rows into arguments to the `vcat` function. For example, let `z = [ a, b, c ]`, then `f(z...)` is the same as `f(a, b, c)`, which in general is not the same as `f(z)`.